# Who do I contact regarding rights licenses of specific manga/anime characters?

Tags: licensing

My company runs a card game in Europe, but we want to start including manga and anime characters. How would we start going about obtaining licences?

We want Akira, Fist of the North Star, Ako, Tank Police, Appleseed, etc.

It's just one image character per card. Does anyone have any details on doing this legally and respectfully, with links, etc?

Comment: I'm not that sure, but I think you should contact the publisher, which in case of for example Akira is 株式会社講談社, Kodansha LTD.

Comment: Note that you may run afoul of existing license agreements in some cases, if someone else in your region holds the appropriate license.  For example, the fact there's a Pokémon card game likely makes using any characters from that series more difficult.  Note that there's already a card game using characters from multiple series, at least here in Japan (possibly all from the same publisher), so don't be too surprised if the answer is "no".

Answer (score 3):

We can't really help you with the process licensing (since we have no expertise on it, so it's off topic), but we can tell you who the primary IP holder are for their respective media.

Akira, [Kodansha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodansha)

Fist of the North Star, [Shueisha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shueisha)

Project A-ko, [Seishinsha](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/company.php?id=1609), [A.P.P.P.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.P.P.P.)

Tank Police, [Hakusensha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakusensha)

Appleseed, [Kodansha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodansha)

Essentially you'll have to contact the IP holder directly to work things out. You might be able to contact your local license holder to get the contact information of the IP holder. Additionally, if you can reach out to the series creators, they can better refer you to the right person.