# Can I have a license for cloth production with anime images?

Tags: naruto, copyright

I need to know if I can put an anime character, for example, Naruto or someone else, you name it, on clothes which I will sell afterwards. Can I do it without any permission of the creators of the anime (guess not but still)? And if I can't how can I get lawful permission for that. I see many things with characters on them and I'm wondering how to not break the copyrights because I want everything to be legal.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/61352/1458) perhaps answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to do it will be by asking the owner of the copyright of the anime Boruto: Naruto Next Generations which is “d-rights Inc”. You can find that by searching up on google, “Who owns the copyright of Boruto: Naruto Next Generations”. You can search up other anime copyright owners to ask them, but take note that sometimes when you want to use someone’s work they may ask you for money like for some google images you need to buy them in order to use them for money.